# Subprocess is running my command but not printing the real-time output

Tags: python, asynchronous, subprocess, discord

I am trying to print the real-time output of an async discord program that prints live messages from my channel continuously using subprocess so I can display the output of my program in a gui app. The issue I am running into is that the code works perfectly at printing real-time terminal outputs of any program except the ones I use discord.py for. Ive checked that it isnt an issue with running the discord.py programs with subprocess because I added a playsound for every new message that comes in and when I run the script with the subporcess program it plays the sounds as it should. However, the issue is only that the output is not printing through the stdout like it does when I just run the script outright outside of subprocess. I just was wondering if anyone knows what I could be missing here? Would it be an incompatibility issue with subprocess or maybe with subprocess and async? Really kind of lost.

Heres the code im using for reference:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('insert_command_here', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    if output:
        print(output.strip())
```

Comment: Is the output actually written to stout and not stderr?

Comment: Output is buffered; it needs to be flushed.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes it is stdout, ive tried with stderr.

Comment: @jrd1 Ah perfect. Added flush=True to my discord.py print statements. Thank you!

Comment: @mattwatkins It's my pleasure!